# why does my first input does not displays?

Tags: c, console

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100], subject1[100], subject2[100], stdsignature[100], advisorsignature[100];
    char code1[7], code2[7], stdID[7];
    int credit1, credit2, total;

    printf ("Universiti of Gambang \n");
    printf ("Subjects Registration Form \n");

    printf ("Name: ");
    fflush (stdin);
    fgets ( name , 100 , stdin );

    printf ("Student ID: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&stdID);

    printf ("Total subjects for every semester must be 2 \nSubject name 1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&subject1);

    printf ("Subject code 1: ");
    scanf ("%s",&code1);

    printf ("Credit 1: ");
    scanf ("%d",&credit1);

    printf ("Subject name 2: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&subject2);

    printf ("Subject code 2: ");
    scanf ("%s",&code2);

    printf ("Credit 2:");
    scanf ("%d",&credit2);

    total= credit1 + credit2;

    printf ("Total %d \n",total);


    printf ("Advisor's signature ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&advisorsignature);

    printf ("                                         Universiti of Gambang \n");
    printf ("                                       Subjects Registration Form \n");

    printf ("================================================================================================================ \n");

    printf ("Name: %s \n",name);
    printf ("Student ID: %s \n",stdID);
    printf ("Total subject: 2 \n");

    printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("     Subject name                            Subject code                            Credit                    \n");
    printf ("          %s                                       %s                                 %d \n",subject1 ,code1,credit1);
    printf ("          %s                                       %s                                 %d \n",subject2 ,code2,credit2);
    printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("     Total credits                                                                    %d \n ",total             );

    printf ("Academic Advisor: %s \n",advisorsignature);

    return 0;
}
.
```

I do not know where does my first input goes. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: 1. The above code works fine for me, can you elaborate your issue?
2. You need to keep the code snippet in one block.

Comment: `stdID[7]` --> `stdID[8]` : length of ID is 7, +1 for null terminator.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thnks.

Comment: ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: The function: `fflush()` is only defined for output streams, not input streams.  To flush an input stream, use something like: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`  Note: that mess known as Visual Studio also defined `fflush()` for input streams, but that is not part of the standard library definition of the functionality for `fflush()`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input/conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid any buffer overflow.  Any such overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Note: when referencing an array, just pass the name of the array as a parameter, that name will decay to the address of the first char of the array. No need for an address of an address

Comment: there is the problem that the displayed data is only allowing room for 41 chars (for alignment) but the actual inputs to be displayed can be up to 99 chars long.  Suggest, for the display to use: `%40:40s` and reduced the input field declarations to 41 characters.

Comment: the posted code is using several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. (like 7, 100)  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your program gives warnings mentioned by santhosh.

Two things,

1) You haven't provided `&` while taking integer input for `int` variable `credit1` and `credit2`.
Use `&` for integer variables in `scanf`,

`scanf ("%d",&credit1);
..
scanf ("%d",&credit2);`

2) You don't need to provide `&` while taking character inputs. 
In C, string is an array of characters. When we pass an array then it actually points to the address of the first element of an array.

So there is no need to use "&" in scanf while taking inputs in an array.

Regarding your issue, Your program gives expected output. Can you please provide more details ?

Answer (score 0):

As BLUEPIXY mentioned, this code snippet gives output, except that there are few warnings.
Below are more details,

```
In function ‘main’:
ex.c:30:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[7]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf ("%s",&stdID);
 ^
ex.c:34:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf ("%s",&subject1);
 ^
ex.c:37:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[7]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf ("%s",&code1);
 ^
ex.c:44:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf ("%s",&subject2);
 ^
ex.c:47:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[7]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf ("%s",&code2);
 ^
ex.c:59:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf ("%s",&advisorsignature);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100], subject1[100], subject2[100], stdsignature[100], advisorsignature[100];
    char code1[50], code2[50], stdID[50];
    int credit1, credit2, total;

    printf ("Universiti of Gambang \n");
    printf ("Subjects Registration Form \n");

    printf ("Name: ");
    gets ( name );
    fflush (stdin);

    printf ("Student ID: ");
    scanf (" %s",&stdID);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf ("Total subjects for every semester must be 2 \nSubject name 1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&subject1);

    printf ("Subject code 1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&code1);

    printf ("Credit 1: ");
    scanf ("%d",&credit1);

    printf ("Subject name 2: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&subject2);

    printf ("Subject code 2: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&code2);

    printf ("Credit 2:");
    scanf ("%d",&credit2);

    total= credit1 + credit2;

    printf ("Total %d \n",total);

    printf ("Student's signature ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&stdsignature);

    printf ("Advisor's signature ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%s",&advisorsignature);

    printf ("                                         Universiti of Gambang \n");
    printf ("                                       Subjects Registration Form \n");

    printf ("================================================================================================================ \n");

    printf ("Name : %s \n",name);
    printf ("Student ID: %s \n",stdID);
    printf ("Total subject: 2 \n");

    printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("     Subject name                            Subject code                            Credit                    \n");
    printf ("          %s                                       %s                                 %d \n",subject1 ,code1,credit1);
    printf ("          %s                                       %s                                 %d \n",subject2 ,code2,credit2);
    printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("     Total credits                                                                    %d \n ",total             );

    printf ("Academic Advisor: %s \n",advisorsignature);

    return 0;
}
```

So, I manage to solve the missing input of mine by manipulate some of the codes. thanks for your responds gais. [image]